# List links leaves unwanted space between left border and first list item. Why?

Tags: html, css

Why does an inline-block list of links leaves unwanted space between left border of div and first item in list. Check out the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZGvUN/) I have created.

Code: HTML

```
<body>

<!--Header area containing logo and contact info-->
<div id="header">
<div class="container">
    <div id="logo"></div>

    <div id="right_header_info">
        <div id="links"> 
            <a href="#">Login</a>
            <a href="#">Register</a>
            <a href="#">Register</a>
            <a href="#">Register</a>
        </div>

        <div id="search">
            <form action="search.php" method="post">
                <input type="search" name="search" id="search_field"/>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="" id="search_btn" />
            </form>
          </div>
      </div>
     </div>
   </div>

<!--Top Menu-->
<div id="top_menu">
    <div class="container">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">New Arrivals</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
    </ul>

    </div>
</div>

<!--Content Area-->
<div id="content">
<div class="container">CONTENT AREA</div>
</div>

<!--Footer-->
<div id="footer">
<div class="container">FOOTER STUFF</div>
</div>
```

Code: CSS

```
.container {
    margin:0 auto;
    width:980px;
    text-align:left;
    border:1px solid white;


}

#top_menu {
    background:url(img/top_menu_bar_bg.png) repeat-x;
}

#top_menu ul{
    list-style-type:none;
}

#top_menu ul li{
    display:inline-block;
}

#top_menu ul > li > a 
{
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #ffffff;
    line-height: 14px;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding-top: 11px;
    padding-right: 18px;
    padding-bottom: 11px;
    padding-left: 18px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    z-index: 6;
    position: relative;
    font-weight: bold;

}

#top_menu .container > ul > li:hover > a 
{
    background-color: #000;
    background-image: none;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    background-attachment: scroll;
    background-position: 0% 0%;

}

#content{
    background-color:#3300CC;        
}

#footer {
    background-color:#C60;        
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not just left padding on the `ul`? Maybe you want something like this http://jsfiddle.net/ZGvUN/1/

Comment: thanks. very silly of me to have completely overlooked padding in ul. BTW, you were the first to suggest a solution, how can i vote up your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `<UL>` has a default padding-left of 40px

Set the padding to 0

```
.container ul{

padding-left:0;

}
```

Comment: It's a good idea to use a set of 'reset' css styles that eliminate these little quirks of HTML elements that often cause cross-browser issues. Plenty of resources on the net for this.

Comment: thanks, a link for beginner to reset CSS Styles would help, rather than a link sea for whoever cares to call himself whatever courtesy Google

Comment: This chap's pretty reliable for a starter: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correct your problem you can just add :

```
ul {
   padding-left: 0;
}
```

to your css.